# formArray without using ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually I try to code **formArray** without using ***ngFor**. It is posible?. I try to code but it come out error. This my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-zluf5b) demo code

**html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="addressForm">
<div formArrayName="addressList">
<div formGroupName="1">
 <div>
 street <input formControlName="street">
 </div>

 <div>
 city <input formControlName="city">
 </div>
</div>
<div formGroupName="2">
 <div>
 street <input formControlName="street">
 </div>

 <div>
 city <input formControlName="city">
 </div>
</div>
<div formGroupName="3">
 <div>
 street <input formControlName="street">
 </div>

 <div>
 city <input formControlName="city">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my component code

**Component**

```
form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: [],
      address: fb.array([this.addressGroup()])
    })
  }


  addressGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      street: [],
      city: []
    })
  }


  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
```

Hope you all can help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you don't want to use ngFor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mapping wrong `formGroupName` like `1` and `2` instead of `0` and `1`.
And one more thing is that you are adding only item in your form array.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: [],
      address: fb.array([this.addressGroup()])
    })
    this.add();
  }

  add() {
    let values = this.form.get('address') as FormArray;
    values.push(this.addressGroup());
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div formGroupName="0">
    <div>
        street <input formControlName="street">
    </div>
    <div>
        city <input formControlName="city">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div formGroupName="1">
    <div>
        street <input formControlName="street">
    </div>
    <div>
        city <input formControlName="city">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-7stqcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: if you dont mind...Can I ask you one more question...`formGroupName` just limit to `1`?.. when I add `formGroupName='2'` I got this error `Error: Cannot find control with path: 'address -> 2'`

Comment: you need to push in `address` formArray like that `add()` function

Answer (score 0):

hello please make this changes

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  street <input formControlName="name">
  
  <div formGroupName="address">

      <div>
        street <input formControlName="street">
      </div>
      <div>
        city <input formControlName="city">
      </div>
  <div>
  </div>

    <button>Submit </button>
      </div>
</form>

    result <br>
    
    <pre>
    {{form.value | json}}
    </pre>
```

**.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl,FormArray } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
     'address': this.fb.group({
          city: null,
          street : null
        }),
    })
  }

 
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
}
```